# php can not detect the existed session and run session_start() per new request

Tags: php, apache, session, session-variables, php-ini

i started session at the start of my `index.php` as per below

```php
<?php
if ( !isset($_SESSION) ) {
    ini_set( 'session.save_path', realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/tmp'));
    umask(0);
    // session_status(); >> 1
    session_start();
}
```

and use 2 classes which first one sets session and second one reads session

> Login.php

```php
<?php

class Login
{
    public function getUser() {

        if ( isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] === "test" ) {

            $_SESSION['current_user'] = "test";
            // session_status(); >> 2

            ?>
        
            {
                "status": true
            }
    
            <?php
    
        } else {

            ?>

            {
                "status": false
            }
    
            <?php
    
        }
```

by running this script will create a new session file as `sess_to43...` in mentioned path and its contains `current_user|i:test;`
so far i have a session file

then in second class which calls by frontend immediately after Login class response:

> Auth.php

```php
<?php

class Auth
{
    public function getSession() {

        var_dump($_SESSION);

    }
```

which returns `NULL` and when i look at the session directory on server, can see new session file which is empty and means php runs `session_start()` again, so
even thought i used `session_start()` at start and before both of classes, the php can not recognize current existed session

additionally as you can see i set different path for session files and all new sessions store in this directory correct but this simple script can not handle the sessions

is there any reason in `php.ini` or Apache server causes unset created session per new requests?

> P.S. PHP version: 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here:

```
    echo session_status(); // 1
    session_start();
```

You're sending output to the browser BEFORE starting your session.  Try:

```
    $x = session_status(); // 1
    session_start();
    echo $x;
```

Comment: thanks for comment, it was only for show the status, there isnt in actual code, means even with your code it doesnt work and as i mentioned might be some server config

Comment: No idea then.   I'd suggest trying to create a session WITHOUT your code-- one page to create the session, set a variable, and report success... one page to load the session and read the variable.  If that fails, you know it's the server and not your code.

Comment: thank you again, yes it seems the code works since i have access to server and can see every single new session file but it is weird that the second request to read created session caused to run `session_start()`